# Detect when the speech (TTS) has really finished

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm using the following code to convert text to speech (`TTS`) and using the `setOnUtteranceProgressListener.onDone` to detect when the speech has finished, however the onDone method is called while the text is still being read. Is it possible to detect when the reading is really done?

```
private fun speakSimple(content: String, utteranceId: String, flush: Boolean = false) {
        mTTS?.speak(content, if (flush) TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH else TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, utteranceId)
        mUtteranceId = utteranceId
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversation, container, false)

        mBotPhraseText = mView!!.findViewById(R.id.botPhraseText)
        mInteractionOptionsContainer = mView!!.findViewById(R.id.interactionOptionsContainer)

        requestRecordAudioPermission()

        mTTS = TextToSpeech(context!!, this)

        mTTS?.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : UtteranceProgressListener() {
            override fun onError(utteranceId: String?) {

            }

            override fun onDone(utteranceId: String?) {
                // This part is executed even before the speech is completed
                }
            }


            override fun onStart(utteranceId: String?) {

            }

        })
```

Comment: onDone has always worked properly for me.  And the documentation says "[when onDone is called], All audio will have been played back by this point for audible output" ... so, what device and API level are you testing on, and what engine is being used by the TTS?  Is it a very large block of text being spoken or something very short?  Is onDone() being called immediately after onStart()?  How early is it being called?  Does this problem happen only when using QUEUE_FLUSH, QUEUE_ADD, or both?  Also, if you are sending multiple utterances in succession, are you matching the unique utteranceIDs?

Answer (score 0):

The [TTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) doesn't provide such callback. The one you are referring to, [UtteranceProgressListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener) notifies listeners for synthesising events. The documentation for setting the listeners mentions:

> Sets the listener that will be notified of various events related to the synthesis of a given utterance.

So, the `onDone` callback that you receive is about synthesising. The TTS service informs you that all the text has been processed/prepared. Even though, TTS speaks it doesn't mean that the whole text has been synthesised.

You can achieve what you want by using [`synthesizeToFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)) instead of speak and when you receive the `onDone` method from the `UtteranceProgressListener` to pass the synthesised file into a [media player](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) service or [exoplayer](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html#library-overview)(which provides such listeners), where it's a bit easier to keep track or manipulate events like start, resume, pause and stop.